# How get by code list of default Groovy imports

Tags: groovy

I want to get **programmatically** in any form a list of default packages imported by Groovy. Like the documentation says:

All these packages and classes are imported by default, i.e. you do not have to use an explicit import statement to use them:
    java.io.*

```
java.lang.*

java.math.BigDecimal

java.math.BigInteger

java.net.*

java.util.*

groovy.lang.*

groovy.util.*
```

In others words, check whether import is required (for any classes out of this list) or not.
The List should be valid for current version and potentially for future versions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The static variable `org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.DEFAULT_IMPORTS` is an array of `String`​ that contains all default imported package names.

Currently it's (printed) value is:

```
[java.lang., java.io., java.net., java.util., groovy.lang., groovy.util.]
```

Check the [ResolveVisitor doc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/ResolveVisitor.html#DEFAULT_IMPORTS) for more info. If you want to know how to add custom packages to the defaults check [this Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3041).